# Lazy load an ICompositeUserType

Tags: nhibernate

I have a `class MoneyCompositeUserType : ICompositeUserType`

Which I use like so in a mapping:

```
public InvoiceMap()
{
    Table("Invoices");
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Customer);
    Map(x => x.Number);
    Map(x => x.TotalValue)
        .CustomType(typeof(MoneyCompositeUserType))
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("TotalValue_Amount", "TotalValue_Currency");
}
```

And here is the class:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual string Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Money TotalValue { get; set; }
}
```

I thought that the value would be lazy loaded, that's the point of the `virtual` right? But the `NullSafeGet` method of the composite user type is called when the item is loaded. Here is my failing test:

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    var fromDb = session.Get<Invoice>(invoice.Id);
    Assert.IsFalse(NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.IsPropertyInitialized(fromDb, "TotalValue"));
}
```

Why is that property not being lazy loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that the value would be lazy loaded, that's the point of the virtual right?

Not exactly -- NHibernate needs your properties to be `virtual` so that it can use a proxy class in place of your class to *enable* lazy loading. Lazy loading is not enabled just because a property is marked virtual.

I believe all you should have to do is mark the individual property with `.LazyLoad` in your mapping (see [lazy properties](http://ayende.com/blog/4377/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties) for more information):

```
Map(x => x.TotalValue)
    .LazyLoad() // <-----
    .CustomType(typeof(MoneyCompositeUserType))
    .Columns.Clear()
    .Columns.Add("TotalValue_Amount", "TotalValue_Currency");
```